# Processing runalg gdalogr Error: Algorithm not found

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I can not use the "gdalogr"-Processing in  QGIS 3.0 (2.99) 
QGIS code revision 1182816

```
import processing
processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat','', 0, '' ,'')
Error: Algorithm not found
```

Does anyone know whats going  wrong?

Comment: Likely due to the software being in development and maybe a question for the QGIS dev list?

Answer (score 1):

Over "QGIS dev list":

> It's because gdalogr no longer exists in 3.0, use instead gdal. You could to run processing.alglist() to get the write syntax of functions.

I use

```
processing.runalg('gdal:convertformat'  ...
```

This works (in the principle).

Comment: Shouldn't it be processing.run('gdal:convertformat' ... ? processing.runalg throws up AttributeError: module 'processing' has no attribute 'runalg'